# Dúvida sobre Down votes Up votes

Tags: debate

## Cenário hipotético

Imaginem que um usuário possui menos de 125 pontos de privilégio e resolveu votar a favor em uma pergunta ou resposta, porém, suponha que o autor da resposta modificou de tal forma que o usuário não concorda mais com a resposta. Nesse caso ele deseja retirar o up vote que deu anteriormente, mas não pode porque não possui 125 privilégios.

Nessa situação o down vote não deveria ser possível? não há nada a fazer? por que existe diferença entre retirar o voto e votar contra?

Comment: **Retirar** o voto é diferente de **Downvote**... Se o autor mudou a resposta será possivel tirar o upvote já dado e se deseja negativar a pergunta é esperar o privilégio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retirar voto é diferente de mudar o voto.

> Nessa situação o down vote não deveria ser possível?

Não. Não existe motivo para que sejam abertas exceções às regras do site.

> não há nada a fazer?

Você sempre pode retirar seu voto a qualquer momento, se após o voto a publicação tiver sido editada. Se não tiver sido editada, você tem uma janela de alguns minutos para retirar ou mudar o voto.

> por que existe diferença entre retirar o voto e votar contra?

Porque existem três formas diferentes de se reagir a uma publicação com relação a votos. Se você igualar duas delas, você acaba tendo duas opções ao invés de três - assim você tem um modelo mais simples, mas que não reflete o modelo do SO.